# How to maintain multiple values for key in resx file c#

Tags: c#, resx

I want to maintain 2 values for one key like this

**Key**   ,              **value**           ,                           **code**

InvalidcardMessage        ,     Invalid card details           ,               4

In resx file I found only one value for key. How to maintain these values in my project globally like resource file? Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Resx are for localizable resources, it's not a value store to save application data. If second value is a localizable item (an image, for example) you'd better to use a separate resource (instead of index). If it's just an unlocalizable index you may use an external application data file.

Comment: Do you want these values to be localizable?

Comment: yes Matthew. I want these values to be localizable.

Answer (score 1):

Why not *combine* `value` and `code` into one string using, say, *comma* (',') as a separator? So in the resx file it will be

```
 key   = "InvalidcardMessage"
 value = "Invalid card details,4"
```

To get `value` and `code` all you should do is to *split* by comma:

```
  String[] values = Resources.InvalidcardMessage.Split(',');

  String value = values[0];         // "Invalid card details"
  int code = int.Parse(values[1]);  // 4
```